# SQLite return multiple rows from a date range subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite, date-range

I am trying to return all rows from my 'Register' table that satisfy all date ranges specified by the rows in a closure table.  The following query returns register entries for the corresponding first row of the closure table:

```
select * from Register where NOT(start_time > (select EndDate from Closures) OR start_time  < (select StartDate from Closures)) group by id;
```

The closure table has the following start and end dates:

```
"2018-09-21"    "2018-09-27"
"2018-06-12"    "2018-06-12"
"2018-06-10"    "2018-06-12"
"2018-06-15"    "2018-06-15"
"2018-06-19"    "2018-06-24"
```

but the query above only returns rows from Register as if the subquery returned 2018-09-21 and 2018-09-27, how do I get it to essentially run the outer query for all rows of the subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you want to inner join `register` like that?

```
SELECT r.*
       FROM register r
            INNER JOIN closures c
            ON c.enddate >= r.start_time
               and c.startdate <= r.start_time;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start, however if I have a closure date that starts and ends on the same day (closed for one day) the query does not return the result of any register entries for that day

Comment: Since the register field is a timestamp I changed the query to include date(r.start_time) and then it worked as intended